# Disjoint sets implementation

Tags: algorithm, scala

I would like to get some feedback on the following implementation of disjoint sets, based on disjoint-sets forests (*Cormen, et.al., Introduction to Algorithms, 2nd ed., p.505ff*). It should have the following properties:

- Abstracts away all internal data structures and can be used to create disjoint sets of any type `T`
- Supports the traditional disjoint set operations: `add`, `union`, `find`
- Performs union-by-rank and path compression optimizations

Any general advice is welcome, but I have my doubts in particular about the following points:

- Mixture of object-oriented and functional programming - it feels like best of both worlds, but I'm always unsure on which side to lean stronger.
- Thread-safety: is it sufficient to synchronize the public methods and initialization? is it necessary? (not sure about `add` and `size`)
- The `MatchError`: what is a best practice to deal with this sort of thing?

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

/**
 * This class implements a disjoint-sets algorithm with
 * union-by-rank and path compression. The forest/sets/etc. are
 * internal data structures not exposed to the outside. Instead,
 * it is possible to add new elements (which end up in a newly
 * created set), union two elements, and hence, their sets, and
 * find the representative of a disjoint-set by a given element of
 * the set.
 */
class DisjointSets[T](initialElements : Seq[T] = Nil) {

  /**
   * Add a new single-node forest to the disjoint-set forests. It will
   * be placed into its own set.
   */
  def add(elem : T) : Unit = synchronized {
    nodes += (elem -> DisjointSets.Node(elem, 0, None))
  }

  /**
   * Union the disjoint-sets of which <code>elem1</code> 
   * and <code>elem2</code> are members of.
   * @return the representative of the unioned set
   * @precondition elem1 and elem2 must have been added before
   */
  def union(elem1 : T, elem2 : T) : T = synchronized {
    // lookup elements
    require(nodes.contains(elem1) && nodes.contains(elem2), 
        "Only elements previously added to the disjoint-sets can be unioned")

    // retrieve representative nodes
    (nodes.get(elem1).map(_.getRepresentative), 
     nodes.get(elem2).map(_.getRepresentative)) match {
      // Distinguish the different union cases and return the new set representative

      // Case #1: both elements already in same set
      case (Some(n1), Some(n2)) if n1 == n2 => 
        n1.elem

      // Case #2: rank1 > rank2 -> make n1 parent of n2
      case (Some(n1 @ DisjointSets.Node(_, rank1, _)), 
            Some(n2 @ DisjointSets.Node(_, rank2, _))) if rank1 > rank2 =>
        n2.parent = Some(n1)
        n1.elem

      // Case #3: rank1 < rank2 -> make n2 parent of n1
      case (Some(n1 @ DisjointSets.Node(_, rank1, _)), 
            Some(n2 @ DisjointSets.Node(_, rank2, _))) if rank1 < rank2 =>
        n1.parent = Some(n2)
        n2.elem

      // Case #4: rank1 == rank2 -> keep n1 as representative and increment rank
      case (Some(n1 @ DisjointSets.Node(_, rank1, _)), 
            Some(n2 @ DisjointSets.Node(_, rank2, _))) /*if rank1 == rank2*/ =>
        n1.rank = rank1 + 1
        n2.parent = Some(n1)
        n1.elem

      // we are guaranteed to find the two nodes in the map,
      // and the above cases cover all possibilities
      case _ => throw new MatchError("This should never have happened")
    }
  }

  /**
   * Finds the representative for a disjoint-set, of which
   * <code>elem</code> is a member of.
   */
  def find(elem : T) : Option[T] = synchronized {
    nodes.get(elem) match {
      case Some(node) =>
        val rootNode = node.getRepresentative
        // path compression
        if (node != rootNode) node.parent = Some(rootNode)
        Some(rootNode.elem)
      case None => None
    } 
  }

  /**
   * Returns the number of disjoint-sets managed in this data structure.
   * Keep in mind: this is a non-vital/non-standard operation, so we do 
   * not keep track of the number of sets, and instead this method recomputes 
   * them each time.
   */
  def size : Int = synchronized {
    nodes.values.count(_.parent == None)
  }

  ////
  // Internal parts
  private val nodes : scala.collection.mutable.Map[T, DisjointSets.Node[T]] = 
    scala.collection.mutable.Map.empty

  // Initialization
  synchronized { initialElements map (add _) }
}

object DisjointSets {
  def apply[T](initialElements : Seq[T] = Nil) = new DisjointSets[T](initialElements)

  ////
  // Internal parts
  private case class Node[T](val elem : T, var rank : Int, var parent : Option[Node[T]]) {
    /**
     * Compute representative of this set.
     * @return root element of the set
     */
    @tailrec
    final def getRepresentative: Node[T] = parent match {
      case None => this
      case Some(p) => p.getRepresentative
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, Sylvain Conchon and J.C. Filliatre have an axiomatized (and proven correct) implementation in "A Persistent Union-Find Data Structure" which reads in Ocaml... I was trying to find a ready-made implementation and found both your work and theirs... I'm off to code my own now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling that your `find` is suboptimal. I'd say you should compress the whole path up to the root, not just the parent of the single node. So you should find the root node first and then traverse the path again and set `parent` to `Some(rootNode)` for all of the nodes.

Concerning `MatchError`s, I'd perhaps use

```
def union(elem1 : T, elem2 : T) : T =
  // retrieve representative nodes
  (nodes.get(elem1).map(_.getRepresentative), 
   nodes.get(elem2).map(_.getRepresentative)) match {
    case (Some(n1), Some(n2)) if n1 == n2 => // ...

    // ...

    case _ => // one of the values is None
        require(false,
            "Only elements previously added to the disjoint-sets can be unioned")
  }
```

---

Concerning synchronization, I'd let the user pick if (s)he wants a synchronized implementation or not. I'd define a trait with all the operations (that's always a good idea to separate the contract):

```
trait DisjointSets[T] {
    def add(elem : T) : Unit;
    def union(elem1 : T, elem2 : T) : T;
    def find(elem : T) : Option[T];
    def size : Int;
}
```

and then something like

```
class DisjointSetsImpl[T] private (initialElements : Seq[T] = Nil)
    extends DisjointSets[T]
{
    // ...
}
```

and then a wrapper (either explicit or just within a method on the companion object)

```
class DisjointSetSync[T](val underlying: DisjointSet[T])
    extends DisjointSet[T]
{
    override def add(elem: T) : Unit = synchronized {
        underlying.add(elem);
    }

    // etc.
}
```

You will need to synchronize all public operations, including `add` and `size` (consider one thread is reading the `size` while the other one is adding a new element to the set using `add`).

This way users can use faster, default, non-synchronized implementation, and wrap it into a synchronized one, if needed. In most cases, users will want their own synchronization anyway, because they often use other synchronization primitives (such as locks or semaphores) or need to synchronize several operations at once.

Also, you don't need to synchronize initializing code such as

```
// Initialization
synchronized { initialElements map (add _) }
```

because at the time of the initialization of an object, nobody has a reference to it yet, so it's not possible that other threads access it concurrently.

I'd perhaps use a different name for `size`, something like `setCount`, because it can be easily confused with the number of elements, not the number of disjoint sets. You could also make `size` faster by keeping count of the number of distinct sets, and just decrementing it after each successful `union`. (I vaguely recall that this operation was useful for some algorithm, but I can't remember which one.)

You could also consider extending Scala's standard traits (after renaming `size`) to make your class even more useful:

- `Growable` (this would replace `add` with `+=`).
- `Traversable` which would traverse all elements in all sets.
- `PartialFunction[T,T]` to find a representative for a node (if it's in the set - this would be a synonym for `find`).

This won't cost you anything and can be useful sometimes.

---

There has been [a request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17409641/1333025) for an implementation like yours, perhaps you could consider publishing it as a small library somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the excellent remarks from Petr:

I think you could gain some storage efficiency and reduce the number of temporary objects by having parent as a field of Node[T] (instead of having a parent of type Option[Node[T]]). You would just initialize it with this (which is the correct initial value).

```
object DisjointSets {
  def apply[T](initialElements : Seq[T] = Nil) = new DisjointSets[T](initialElements)

  ////
  // Internal parts
  private case class Node[T](val elem : T, var rank : Int) {

    var parent: Node[T] = this

    /**
     * Compute representative of this set.
     * @return root element of the set
     */

    @tailrec
    final def getRepresentative: Node[T] = 
      if(parent eq this) this else parent.getRepresentative
    } 
  }
}
```

Regarding synchronization: I wouldn't bother. Keep it completely out of your code, and put a big warning in the docs that the thing is not thread-safe. When people want to use it in a multithreaded context they will probably have to put a lock around it anyway because they have multiple data structures that they need to keep synchronized. And in scala mutable data structures are mostly used from safe context such as the internal state of an actor. For this use case synchronization by default would just add additional overhead.